# Why do we say that a plane is "en route"?

Tags: etymology

My primary language being French, I can clearly understand what *en route* means ("on its way"). I can't see, however, why English-speaking people would use this French expression.

Why is it used?

Comment: This question seems as relevant to English as to French, really; both use the term in basically the same way, as you alluded to.  You may want to think of committing to the [French Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language-usage?referrer=vTzHM5nwvlxiQVNB5HAzXQ2) proposal.

Comment: As it stands, I feel this question is not answerable.  Something similar that comes closer to "Why are there loanwords for phrases that have perfectly sensible English translations?" might be more *apropos*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**On the way** can mean a number of things:
 - in transit (to):  "Flight 105 is on its way to Los Angeles"
 - going the right direction:  "He set them on their way"
 - along/beside the path:  "On our way, we saw a lot of wildflowers."

By contrast, **en route** (in English usage, anyway) only means "in transit (to)."  It can be quite useful to use a word or phrase with no ambiguity.  Also, from my (admittedly brief) review of Ngrams/Google Books citations, it seems that the phrase was first brought into English in military contexts; logistics is certainly a field where clarity and concision are prized.

Answer (score 3):

I have studied English for a long time, and one of my pet projects has been to find words that originated in the British Isles before all the invasions began, a couple of thousand years ago.

To date, I have found precisely 0 (zero) words that cannot be traced back to the languages of the various invaders -- we don't even know the name the Beakers called themselves (the name "Beakers" was given to them because they made a lot of clay beakers).

So finding that we use a word from another language is not at all an unusual event -- *All* of our words come from other languages.

Comment: Yes, there is no English equivalent of the *Academie Francaise*

Comment: EL&U supports UTF8 but not entities in comments so Académie Française

Comment: +1 for the scholarship. It's interesting to note that even the names of the countries of the U.K. were bestowed by the newcomers. *Wales*, for example, was the term used by the Saxon invaders to mean "foreigners"!

Comment: Does the Académie really stop the French from using English phrases?

Comment: @GEdgar:  Yes and no.  The Académie doesn't just say "Thou Shalt Not!", but puts forward (where possible) alternatives that can be used.  Since the alternatives are preferable to a lot of people, they get adopted.

Answer (score 1):

Most languages have adopted "isms" from other languages, when there are few convenient expressions in the first language for a particular concept. "En route" just happens to be a French expression widely adopted in English. Ditto for "savoir faire," "faux pas," or RSVP (Repondez-vous s'il vous plait.)